# Installation problem for neuralprophet in jupyter notebbok with windows

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, conflict, facebook-prophet

When tried to install neuralprophet with pip command in jupyter the following error message is shown,

```
The conflict is caused by:
        neuralprophet 0.2.7 depends on torch<1.7.0 and >=1.4.0
        neuralprophet 0.2.6 depends on torch<1.7.0 and >=1.4.0
        neuralprophet 0.2.5 depends on torch<1.7.0 and >=1.4.0
To fix this you could try to:
    1. loosen the range of package versions you've specified
    2. remove package versions to allow pip attempt to solve the dependency conflict
    
    ERROR: Cannot install neuralprophet==0.2.5, neuralprophet==0.2.6 and neuralprophet==0.2.7 because these package versions have conflicting dependencies.
    ERROR: ResolutionImpossible:
```

Can anyone tell me how to solve these issues?